# Why is there a penalty on large block sizes?

Tags: dynamic-blocksize-limit, blockchain-size, transaction-size, miners-penalty

What problem is the block size penalty trying to solve? If it is just an anti-spam system, aren't there more efficient solutions?

Let's say there are 100 transactions waiting to be included in the blockchain, I can't see the drawback of including all of them in the next block. At the moment, it would take at least 20 blocks to include all of them and stay within the 60kB typical size. I understand that if all the transactions were included in a single block, the next blocks would likely be empty and therefore "waste" space. But 20 empty blocks is probably between 2 and 5 kB so it doesn't seem to be a big deal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the penalty function is inherited from CryptoNote, we must look at the [whitepaper](https://cryptonote.org/whitepaper.pdf) for the "original thought" on the subject.

> A miner still has the ability to stuff a block full of his own zero-fee transactions up to its maximum size `2 * M_b`. Even though only the majority of miners can shift the median value, there is still a possibility to bloat the blockchain and produce an additional load on the nodes. To discourage
>   malevolent participants from creating large blocks we introduce a penalty function:
>
> `NewReward = BaseReward * (BlkSize / M_N - 1) ^ 2`
>
> This rule is applied only when BlkSize is greater than minimal free block size which should be close to `max(10kb, M_N * 110%)`. Miners are permitted to create blocks of “usual size” and even exceed it with profit when the overall fees surpass the penalty. But fees are unlikely to grow quadratically unlike the penalty value so there will be an equilibrium.

We can see that Monero deviates from this as the penalty is triggered for any %. I'm not sure what the reasoning was, but one could assume it had to do with preventing a spam attack. With a free 10% increase, any `>0` fee transactions would be economic for the miner and someone could cheaply keep the blocks growing all by himself for almost no cost. The do-not-relay minimum fee could maybe alone counter this, but I don't have sufficient knowledge to know whether it would be safe to rely on it alone.

I'd say the whole idea is to throttle the rate at which the block size can grow, while allow some pressure to build up and push them upwards should there be a rational need. But why does the growth rate need throttling? Let's see the example given.

> Let's say there are 100 transactions waiting to be included in the blockchain, I can't see the drawback of including all of them in the next block.

That would mean a 1.3MB block. We could probably get away with that. But that would mean a 2067% increase! What if the median was 1.3MB and you had 10000 low-priority transactions? Would you still say it's ok to mine a 130MB block? How would the network deal with that? I'd argue it's common sense not to allow for such shocks. The growth rate must be limited in some way, because the growth rate of everything else is limited by some other mechanisms. Sure, one day we will have 130MB as the norm, but the hardware will be there as well and the network will have grown into it.

These mechanisms are there to ensure smooth functioning of everything while we get there.

It's not just about that. We want some fee pressure. If every TX would get in immediately why would anyone ever raise the fee to "priority"? If the fee was ultra-low, how would you make people use the network rationally? Making the network "work" for someone sending a value of 0.001$ hardly seems rational and long term it could make the system collapse. I wouldn't bend over to pick up 0.1$ and the entire network should store multiple copies of a TX spending 0.001$ and pass it around forever? As we can't know the actual amounts involved, the only way to keep the usage rational is to make it cost something as a kind of "proof of intent".

I'd say the problem is not in the formulas themselves, but just in the starting parameters which were kind of unintentionally changed with introduction of RCT.

Answer (score 5):

If you were a bank, then I agree with you - clearing all transactions as fast as possible makes the most sense for your customers. After all, you would control all the account information, have plenty of computing power, and would enjoy all the transaction fees that go with them.

We don't want centralization, we want as many people as possible to run a full node. That includes people with laptops, older desktops, and smaller cloud instances (like AWS). Increasing the blocksize makes this difficult to achieve since every full node needs to store, validate, and propagate transactions and blocks. Bigger blocks mean more CPU and bandwidth, so there would be a decline in full node numbers. Bad!

With unlimited block sizes I could also maliciously submit invalid large blocks that take a long time to reject.

This would also benefit miners with the largest hashrate. Suppose a large mining pool mines a block with a huge number of transactions. They know it's valid and immediately start mining the next block as they send out their solved block. Being a large block, it takes additional time to validate this block and propagate it to other miners. An additional 10-20 second delay is a great advantage in a 2-minute block cycle.

So to recap, blocksize must increase over time to accommodate increasing transaction volume. The amount of increase will be debatable at any given time given the available bandwidth, and processing power of the network (nodes and miners) as a whole.

Comment: Your second paragraph doesn't really apply - if there are 100 transactions of 15kB each, putting them all in one block of 1.5MB or spreading them over 20 blocks of 75kB each makes very little difference to the total size of the blockchain.

Comment: Your second to last paragraph is also moot, in the sense that the block size is dynamic, and large miners' advantage will grow with block size (it's not a question of if but when).  So you are essentially saying that the only problem the size penalty is trying to solve is malicious operations (i.e. spam).

Comment: In the second paragraph, I wasn't implying storage as an issue. It does make a difference to both bandwidth and CPU requirements. Its equivalent to downloading one tv episode to see if you like the series, or downloading the entire series only to find out you don't like it. That's assuming the entire season you did download wasn't some virus filled folder with no shows at all. If you end up liking the show then yes, in the end the bandwidth is the same, but thats not the point.

The miners advantage is minimized by smaller blocks that grow slowly so the networks total speed can keep up.